# FPDF with lots of images, any way to speed it up?

Tags: performance, image, fpdf

I'm using FPDF with PHP and need to print an order manifest. This manifest will have up to 200-300 products with images. Creating it at this point is quite slow, and the images are stored on AmazonS3. Any idea if this could be sped up?

Right now just with images of about 15X15 mm it generates a file size of about 16mb and takes 3 1/2 to 4 minutes, which without the images is only about 52k and comes up almost instantly.

Of course, it may just be downloading that many images about which there's not really much I can do.

Comment: I am having similar issues, but with local images. It is more or less instant without the images, but take about 15 seconds with them, which is just a little too long. I read something a while back about fpdf struggling with long documents because the whole doc is held in memory during creation, and that there was an extension that allowed it to create the report while only holding one page in memory at time, but i cant for the life of me remember what its called or where i read about it!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to try [`img2pdf`](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf).

While this module offers much less options for interacting with PDFs compared with `fpdf`, if you are only interested in combining images into a PDF file, this is probably the best module you can use. It is fast. It is easy to use.

Here is an example code:

```
import img2pdf

filename = "mypdf.pdf"
images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]
with open(filename,"wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(images))
```

I used it to combine 400 images - it only took a second or so.

Comment: I agree. I tried FPDF with 1200 images, it took forever and I just had to cancel the script (unless i litterally leave it overnight). But using `img2pdf` i can merge 1200 images in 3s and 5300 in barely 20s.

Answer (score 1):

I found the extension i mentioned in my comment above:

http://fpdf.org/en/script/script76.php

this seems to reduce the time it takes a little for myself, you may have better results as your document is much larger than mine.